# Is there any solution to share functions in parasails pages?

Tags: sails.js

I want use same functions in multiple parasails pages. Is there any solution, how this can be achieved? I know about utilities, but I want use same functions with their names. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, i barely know about parasails, but I think utilities are not longer supported in recent versions of sails. If you want to use the same functions in your controllers, place the functions in a single file at api/services. This will make them automatically available in all controllers. If you want the functions to be accessible in the client, then i would do the same but placing the file in assets/dependencies. This will make the functions available in your fronted(in theory, I've never tried it).

Hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but as far as I've tested with Sails, parasails utilities are still supported.

With utilities (since there isn't any of this information on the actual documentation) I name the utility being registered the same as the function name within the utility as seen on their example [SailsJS repo](https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration). Then when calling the utility following the implementation they have for where they use the utility at.

I don't think there is any other way to do it honestly.

Note: the version of sails I tested it with is 1.4 which is the latest and parasails utilities still worked.